# VS2017 Data Lake tools cannot submit U-SQL script to Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Using Visual Studio 2017 with Data Lake Tools v. 2.3.1000.1, I am unable to submit a U-SQL job directly to Azure. I only have the option to submit locally:

[image]

This is the case even though I am connected to Azure through the "Server Explorer" tool window, from which I can access my U-SQL databases, view jobs that were previously submitted to Azure, etc.:

[image]

Using Visual Studio 2015, I have no such issue:

[image]

Am I forgetting a setting or a property somewhere, or is this perhaps a bug in Data Lake Tools for VS2017?

Comment: It is working fine on my setup of Visual Studio 2017. Are you signed in with an account that has access to ADL? The same user as in VS 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the issue?

I sometimes see this happen if I open an existing solution and the tabs are already open, and I have not yet logged in. I then log in and the drop down menu of the open window will not be refreshed.

I close and reopen the script and it normally shows up.

Another reason, that I think will be addressed soon, could be that you have a filter on your cloud view explorer on which subscriptions you expose. If you hid the subscription there with your ADLA account, you will not see it in the pull down.

In any case, please let us know if you still have the issue and none of the two suggestions help.